# How to enable .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 without downloading it?

Tags: windows, .net-framework, windows-8, .net-3.5

Since I installed Windows 8 Preview on my personal computer, during the installation of some programs and drivers (Windows 7 ones) it started to pop me a message warning that [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) Framework 3.5 was needed:

[image]

I could use "Install this feature", start to download some dependencies (300 MB) and that's it, but I don't want to have to download it every time I want to enable this feature on every machine that I install Windows 8.

Is there is some way to install .NET 3.5 on Windows 8 without having to download the entire Framework from Microsoft?

Comment: Is that actually what happens when you click it?  In 7 and 2008 adding the "Features" or "Roles" didn't require an Internet connection to add (just to update, after adding).  Including their in-built .NET version (3.5).

Comment: Yes, it downloads entire Framework from internet, I just checked here without internet and the service timed out.

Comment: Wow, that's lame... then WHY is it still in the Image?  :/

Comment: [Reference.](http://www.yethz.com/win-8/enable-netframework-3-5-in-windows-8-without-using-windows-update/2499/)

Comment: I wonder if the "included" .Net 4.5 does it too then? Bizarre choices over at MS. :)   Also, maybe you should reference your source in your answer (them's the rules ain't they)? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way, but you must have installation media for Windows 8 (could be a DVD or even a mounted .ISO with a Windows 8 installation) and make sure the media is for the correct version of Windows (x32 or x64). Otherwise, the command line will fail (not harmful, just annoying):

- Run a command prompt (`cmd`) with elevated rights ('as Administrator').
- Run the following command:

> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All
>   /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

*where "E:\sources\sxs" is the sxs path of your Windows 8 installation media.*

[image]

- That's it, .NET 3.5 is installed on your machine. Reboot and everything that requires .NET 3.5 will work.

Comment: prompt me : 
__The limitaccsess option is not recognized in this context.__ Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /Source:I:\Sources\sxs  **i run that without limit-access switch, and execute successfully.**

Comment: *The `limitaccsess` option is not recognized in this context.* You can't spell `limitaccess`.