# How do I manage what is in the New context menu in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add an item to the ‘new’ context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)

When you right click on the desktop there is a context menu called "New". How do you manage what is in there in Windows 8?

Comment: [This](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/112102-new-menu-context-file.html) is for vista, does it work?

Comment: @KarthikT It should. The *New* item has worked this way since Windows 95.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to use a GUI program which is very handy in this situation. I'm recommending it because its not good to play with registry when you are not familiar with it.

Just download [new menu editor](http://download.cnet.com/New-Menu-Editor/3000-2248_4-75697760.html) and install it, it need .Net Framework 3.5 or higher to run.

[image]

The right side panel is showing up the entries which are presently in the "New" context menu. You can delete an entry by selecting it and then click on remove button.

[image]

To add an entry in the context menu just select the entry form the left panel and hit the "Add" button.

[image]

You can add the shortcut as an empty file, or as a pre-defined template, and click OK. Before it gets updated, you need to right-click your desktop and select Refresh to view the newly added item in New context menu.

[image]

If it still doesn't show the entry in the menu then just add another entry which you don't want to keep and then delete it again and this time you will see the entry in your New context menu which you added previously.

**Note**: If you have any problem with .Net framework then you can try this [post](https://superuser.com/a/469657/86550) to install it on your machine.

Comment: @Kirk does this not helped? What error you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps,

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<FileExt>`

   **If you want to add a file extension to the New menu:**
3. In the while area, right-click and select `New --> Key`.
4. Type `ShellNew` and press Enter.

   **If you want to remove a file extension to the New menu:**

3. Right-click `ShellNew` and select `Delete`.

Answer (score 1):

its easy to edit it via `regedit`

Just modify the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`

there you will find all the extensions listed
add a new `key` there and type `ShellNew`
It will get added

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct, but only an experienced people can use it effectively (by finding a correct key, editing the registry value, etc). You should consider adding a more specific example in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

another way

1. Open regedit.
2. Navigate yourself to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\`
3. Here you will see the folders listed under `Context MenuHandlers`. When you do right click on one of these folders you have an option to delete or modify data.

you need to choose the folder and then when it is highlighted on the right side you need to right click to edit the data. Click on Modify and in the value data put a minus in front of the value and click ok. The value will be gone..