# How can I add 1 item for several files into `new` context menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, intellij-idea

When I click right mouse button in Windows Explorer I get an option to create a new Folder, Shortcut, Text Document, Microsoft Word Document etc.. I would like to add Intellij IDEA file-based project into this menu, so I can right click and rapidly create new projects in many folders. IDEA's project consist of 3 files and 1 empty folder :

```
src
project.iml
project.ipr
project.iws
```

I have already copied these into `C:\Windows\ShellNew`. I've created `add-ipr.reg` with

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ipr\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

What's next?

Comment: Related: [Add item to “New” context menu in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/638755/add-item-to-new-context-menu-in-windows-8?rq=1)

Comment: @ramhound it is not a duplicate because the answers is not applicable to my question. I am asking about adding FILE TREE as an item, not a single file.

Comment: "I am asking about adding FILE TREE as an item," - What?  You don't indicate that in your question.  So how was I suppose to know?  What makes you think you can even do this?

Comment: The "New" entries in the Context Menu are limited in their capability. They basically hand off a very simple argument (the file type) to a Windows process. This limits what you can create with them. You could write a script that creates or copies these folders to the current location and place it in the Context Menu, but not in the Context Menu > New section.

Comment: You could use the answer here, but substitute a a different set of commands for the batch script: https://superuser.com/questions/395836/how-to-copy-a-list-of-file-names-to-text-file/395838#395838