# Installing .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 8 x64 fails and dism at 65.8% with error code 0x800f081f

Tags: windows, windows-8, .net-framework

I am using Windows 8 x64 and would like to install the .NET Framework 3.5. I've downloaded the full package *dotnetfx35* from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150. Installation fails with `Error: 0x800f081f the source files could not be found`.

Regression:

- I've already read [How to enable .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8 without downloading it?](https://superuser.com/questions/469656/how-to-enable-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-8-without-downloading-it)
- `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:f:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess` fails at 65.8% with error code 0x800f081f
- In my win8 iso file's `sxs` folder, there doesn't exist a `.net x64`

How can I install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8?

[image: Error: 0x800f081f the source files could not be found]

Comment: Are you sure that the F drive is where iso is mounted? Double check in Explorer an make sure you're pointing the /Source option to the correct location.

Comment: yes, I'm dead sure about it

Comment: What iso are you using and where did you get it from?

Comment: If you can access Windows Update, you can install it through the Control Panel as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx

Comment: @DavidMarshall I don't agree with your statement that when you can access Windows Update, that .NET Framework 3.5 can be installed through the Control Panel. In our case the "Control Panel" method returns the 0x800f081f error code where the `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess` command and a newer 8.1 DVD does result in a successful installation of the .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [Enterprise Evaluation ISO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx), mount it and now point to this ISO. This ISO includes the SxS folder.

Comment: And make sure that you don't make any typos in the `dism.exe` command. I for example mistyped a lower case `x` (`/featurename:NetFx3`) instead of the required upper case `X` (`/featurename:NetFX3`).

Answer (score 1):

Enable .Net Framework in *Control Panel » Uninstall or Change Programs*. Turn Windows Features and check the box *Update Windows*.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the formatting options on this site, and use proper capitalization in your posts. Maybe you could expand your answer a little to explain in more detail why this solves the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the security updates KB2966826 and KB2966828 and then install framework from the control panel/ program and features/ turn windows features on